# SQL Server convert function query 

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have used a convert function in one of my Queries

```
Select * from tblMas where FromDate >= CONVERT(varchar(10), @FromDate,112)
```

`@FromDate` is a `Datetime` parameter, I don't know why but this query works fine.

Though it should not as `FromDate` is of `DateTime` field and we are comparing it with `Varchar` field.

`CONVERT(varchar(10), @FromDate, 112)` returns result in `yyyyMMdd` format. I am lost how SQL Server is comparing this and returning right result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be an implicit type conversion from varchar to datetime before the comparison.

If you have a look at the queryplan you will see something like this.

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="[FromDate]&gt;=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),[@FromDate],112),0)">
```

Another way to remove the time part from a datetime.

```
select * 
from tblMas 
where FromDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @FromDate), 0)
```

In SQL Server 2008 you can use

```
select * 
from tblMas 
where FromDate >= cast(@FromDate as date)
```

Comment: Ok, but i think it is not the right way to do it as extra efforts for conversion will be made, what you suggest?